# How to collectively set svg attributes?

Tags: html, css, svg

I have a page with two svg arrows, and the code segment looks like:

```
<div class="button prev-button" v-on:click="prevPage">
    <svg class="button-icon" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-width="1" stroke="rgb(0,0,0)" stroke-opacity="0.2" fill="none" stroke-linejoin="round" viewBox="0 0 5 6" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <path d="M4,0L1,3L4,6" ></path>
    </svg>
</div>
<div class="button next-button" v-on:click="nextPage">
    <svg class="button-icon" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-width="1" stroke="rgb(0,0,0)" stroke-opacity="0.2" fill="none" stroke-linejoin="round" viewBox="0 0 5 6" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <path d="M1,0L4,3L1,6" ></path>
    </svg>
</div>
```

where the two svg attributes are identical. Is there a way to declare them collectively? e.g. something like

```
svg {
    attribute1: value1;
    attribute2: value2;
    ...
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do this. However there are some attributes that can not be manipulated in CSS, like the `d` attribute for example.

```css
svg {
  width: 50px;
}
svg path{
  stroke-linejoin: round;
  stroke-width: 1;
  stroke: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  stroke-opacity: 0.2;
  fill:none;
  stroke-linejoin:round;
}
```

```html
<div class="button prev-button" v-on:click="prevPage">
  <svg class="button-icon" viewBox="0 0 5 6" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <path d="M4,0L1,3L4,6" ></path>
    </svg>
</div>
<div class="button next-button" v-on:click="nextPage">
  <svg class="button-icon" viewBox="0 0 5 6" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <path d="M1,0L4,3L1,6" ></path>
    </svg>
</div>
```

Here you have a [List of SVG Properties You Can Manipulate with CSS](https://css-tricks.com/list-of-svg-properties-you-can-manipulate-with-css/)

Comment: There are some more complicated cases. See [presentation attributes](https://svgwg.org/svg2-draft/styling.html#PresentationAttributes) to understand why a `width` CSS property works on a `<svg>` element, but not on a `<mask>` element. Also, SVG 2 implementation is incomplete in most browsers. Theoretically, the `d` attribute should be writable as a CSS property, but so far no browser implements this.